# Error para encontrar referencia "input" en Unity

Tags: c#, unity

Este es el error que me muestra:

> The name 'input' does not exist in the current context 
>   The name 'vector3' does not exist in the current context

Este es mi codigo:

```
Vector3 mov = new Vector3(
            input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"),
            input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"),
            0
        );

transform.position = vector3.movetowars(
        transform.position,
        transform.position + mov,
        speed * Time.deltatime
    );
```

Estos mis referencias en el archivo:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
```

Comment: ya revisaste que no haga falta instalar alguna dependencia? o agregar una referencia al proyecto?

Answer (score 0):

Primero es importante indicar que **Unity3D** emplea el siguiente sistema de coordenadas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si se observa el **plano**: `adelante, atrás` y `derecha, izquierda` están reservados para los ejes `x` y `z` respectivamente, mientras que el eje `y` corresponde a `arriba, abajo`

Lo anterior implica que:

```
horizontal es X
vertical es Z
```

Es decir, el **Héroe** (o `Jugador`) se moverá con las direcciones por el plano `XZ` y eventualmente subirá o bajará a lo largo del eje `y`

Como se deduce **Unity3D** utiliza [la regla de la mano izquierda](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_de_la_mano_izquierda) y no [la regla de la mano derecha](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regla_de_la_mano_derecha) como **OpenGL**.

Aquí hay un post en inglés que preguntan el por qué de lo anterior *[Unity is a Left-Handed Coordinate System? Why?](https://answers.unity.com/questions/38924/unity-is-a-left-handed-coordinate-system-why.html)*

Por otro lado, el constructor `Vector3` de **Unity3D** recibe todos sus parámetros en formato `float`

```
public Vector3(float x, float y, float z);
```

En tal sentido, dadas las consideraciones anteriores, el código posteado tendría que tener esta forma, incluyendo el `cero` en el eje `y`, pero como `0.0f`:

```
float moverHorizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
float moverVertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

Vector3 mov = new Vector3 (moverHorizontal, 0.0f, moverVertical);
```

Adicionalmente hay que reemplazar `vector3.movetowars` por `Vector3.MoveTowards`

Complementando lo anterior, como por está vía no se puede ver cómo se ha configurado los elementos que se arrastran en **Unity3D** como los `prefab` (jugador, cámara) si se está agregando la física (`RigidBody`) al `Jugador`, etc.

Sugiero se revise este ejemplo -si bien en inglés- como son videos proporcionados por **Unity3D** su visualización facilitará descartar is el error se debe porque no se marco una casilla o no se arrastro algún `prefab` al `script` de `C#` correspondiente:

- Como configurar el juego: *[Setting up the Game](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/setting-game?playlist=17141)*
- Desplazar al jugador: *[Moving the Player](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial/moving-player?playlist=17141)*